# How to deploy tomcat using cargo-maven2-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I want to use cargo-maven2-plugin to deploy the web-app to my other host.(ps: the other host is ubuntu os.)I set the tomcat-users.xml:

```
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-script"/>
```

and add the context to pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <container>
                            <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
                            <type>remote</type>
                    </container>
                    <configuration>
                        <type>runtime</type>
                        <properties>
                            <cargo.hostname>10.23.0.3</cargo.hostname>
                            <cargo.servlet.port>8080</cargo.servlet.port>
                            <cargo.remote.username>admin</cargo.remote.username>
                            <cargo.remote.password>admin</cargo.remote.password>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

and run the maven with:

```
cargo:deploy
```

It doesn't work:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building vmojing-web 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.4:redeploy (default-cli) @ vmojing-web ---
[INFO] [DeployerRedeployMojo] Resolved container artifact org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-core-container-tomcat:jar:1.4.4 for container tomcat7x
[INFO] [mcat7xRemoteDeployer] Redeploying [F:\v11-eclipse-workspace\vmojing\vmojing-web\target\vmojing-web.war]
[INFO] [mcat7xRemoteDeployer] Undeploying [F:\v11-eclipse-workspace\vmojing\vmojing-web\target\vmojing-web.war]
[INFO] [mcat7xRemoteDeployer] Deploying [F:\v11-eclipse-workspace\vmojing\vmojing-web\target\vmojing-web.war]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.564 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-12-03T15:09:00+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/16M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.4:redeploy (default-cli) on project vmojing-web: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.4:redeploy failed: Failed to deploy [F:\v11-eclipse-workspace\vmojing\vmojing-web\target\vmojing-web.war]: FAIL - Deployed application at context path /vmojing-web but context failed to start -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

I have no idea for this error,and I try to check the host's tomcat,it really received the vmojing-web.war in webapps file.But is doesn't work.And I change the pom.xml's hostname to my localhost,it work.Who can tell me why?How should I do?

Comment: what does the `catalina.out` logfile say?

Comment: the message "Deployed application at context path /vmojing-web but context failed to start" indicates the deployment works but the application does not start.

Comment: @wemu yes,you are right.I think it maybe caused by ubuntu OS.Do you have a idea for that?

Comment: @reto thank you,How to Add permissions on my .war file

Comment: what you could try is manually copying the war file into the webapps folder in the tomcat installation (if it runs with a different user make sure the file is readable). When starting tomcat the log files inside TOMCAT_HOME/logs should tell you whats not working. There should be something in there already.